# How can I create a new Paragraph item programmatically in an Ajax form handler?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, paragraphs

I need to add Paragraph fields programmatically to an entity in an AJAX handler.

This is my AJAX callback and how it's added:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_gallery_form') {
    $form['field_gallery_items']['multiple_button_dddd'] =   [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Done, now tell us about you.'),
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'myAjaxCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'form_wrapper',
        'event' => 'change', //Use change instead of click so Drupal doesn't run any validation functions.
      ),
    ];
    $form['debug'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['debug-out'],
      ],
    ];

  }  


function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormState $form_state)  {
  $paragraph3 = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'media',
    'field_caption' => 'Apart from the included Paragraph types, you can create your own simply by going to Structure -> Paragraphs types.',
  ]);
  $paragraph3->save();

  // Now I need to add $paragraph3 to $form['field_gallery_items']['widget']

  return $form;
}
```

I need to add the new Paragraph I created to the widget for the so that when the `$form` is returned I have added a paragraph.

How Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:
1) add an hidden field to my form and populate that field with JS

```
function polaris_drupal_cloudinary_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_gallery_form') {
    // Add field to pass the number of images to be added from GalleryWidget.
    $form['field_gallery_items']['multiple_images_count'] =   [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' =>'1',
      '#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['multiple_images_count'],
      ],
    ];

  }

}
```

2) extend the basic paragraph widget so that more than one paragraph can be added

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\polaris_drupal_cloudinary\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\paragraphs\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\InlineParagraphsWidget;
/**
 * Gallery implementation of the 'entity_reference paragraphs' widget.
 *
 * We need to be able to add more than one Paragraph when the Add Media button is pressed.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "entity_reference_paragraphs_gallery",
 *   label = @Translation("Paragraphs Gallery Items"),
 *   description = @Translation("A paragraphs inline form widget."),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "entity_reference_revisions"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class GalleryWidget extends InlineParagraphsWidget {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function addMoreSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $button = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    $howMany = $form_state->getUserInput()['multiple_images_count'] > 0 ? $form_state->getUserInput()['multiple_images_count'] : 1;
    // Go one level up in the form, to the widgets container.
    $element = NestedArray::getValue($form, array_slice($button['#array_parents'], 0, -2));
    $field_name = $element['#field_name'];
    $parents = $element['#field_parents'];
    // Increment the items count.
    $widget_state = static::getWidgetState($parents, $field_name, $form_state);
    if ($widget_state['real_item_count'] < $element['#cardinality'] || $element['#cardinality'] == FieldStorageDefinitionInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED) {
      $widget_state['items_count'] += $howMany;
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $widget_state['items_count']; $i++) {
      $form_state->set([$field_name, $i, 'widget', 'fid'], 1);
    }
    if (isset($button['#bundle_machine_name'])) {
      $widget_state['selected_bundle'] = $button['#bundle_machine_name'];
    }
    else {
      $widget_state['selected_bundle'] = $element['add_more']['add_more_select']['#value'];
    }
    static::setWidgetState($parents, $field_name, $form_state, $widget_state);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
}
```